# dying battery, increasing resistance

Tags: batteries, voltage

this is a graph of v-i relationship of a battery (not ideal one since it has internal resistance)

[image]

as you can see, the slope is 1/R, so as time passes by, R increases, therefore, the slope approaches 0. the graph now tend to become horizontal in time, so the open circuit voltage increases in time. but in real life, when battery ages, the open circuit voltage it has should be decreasing, why is then the graph and my intuition dont agree?

this is based from my experience since as i measure the voltage in an old battery, i find it lower than the expected voltage like a brand new one. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "so the open circuit voltage increases in time"

That would be the case if the the short-circuit current remained the same, but that decreases as R increases. So that point moves up the i-axis. At the same time the open-circuit voltage (the so-called cell's EMF) decreases as well, moving that point to the left on the v-axis. That's another reason for the lower short-circuit current. The result will be that the slope of the line will become more shallow.

So a battery is not a fixed voltage with a varying series resistor; the voltage is variable as well.

**Added** (upon Russell's request)

Like I said also open-circuit voltage decreases, which has nothing to do with internal resistance; in an open-circuit there's no current, so also no voltage drop across the internal resistance. It's the cell's actual EMF which decreases:

> In practice, cell EMF depends on temperature and concentration of reactants and products.
>    If the concentration of reactants increases relative to products, the cell reaction becomes more spontaneous and the EMF increases.
>       As the cell operates, the reactants are used up as more product is formed causing the EMF to decrease.

*(from [here](http://www.ausetute.com.au/calcelemf.html))*

Comment: I was going to say the self discharge is acting across the internal resistance, which causes the drop in output voltage.

Comment: You have not addressed his query re why the open circuit voltage of a battery varies as it does. The internal resistance has little to do with the true open circuit voltage.

Comment: @Russell - Updated. Let me know if it needs other additions or clarifications.